# PHP Regex find all capitalize words in string

Tags: php, regex

PHP Regex find all capitalize words in string:

```
$string = "test sample test: 2015. ŽYDRŪNAS PAVARDENIS";

preg_match_all('/\b([A-Z-][\p{L}\pL]+)\b/', $string, $matches);

var_dump($matches);
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(8) "YDRŪNAS"
    [1]=>
    string(10) "PAVARDENIS"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(8) "YDRŪNAS"
    [1]=>
    string(10) "PAVARDENIS"
  }
}
```

Question is where disapear symbol '`Ž`' ?

HOw to modify `regex` expresion, that will be not removed `UTF-8` symbols ?

Code online: [Code](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cf7f0e1b2fc35043cb9b0add163bceb05963782e)

Comment: Try adding the `u` modifier after the closing `/` delimiter.

Comment: `Ž` is not captured because your regex specifies that the match must start with an uppercase letter between `A` and `Z` or a dash (`-`). More, `\p{L}` is equivalent with `\pL` (you can use any of them) and it includes lowercase letters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically you need to use the [modifier `u`](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) option when working with unicode strings. However the regex can also get simplified using the [`:upper:` character class](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.character-classes.php) because it will match all uppercased unicode characters.

Like this:

```
$string = "test sample test: 2015. ŽYDRŪNAS PAVARDENIS";

preg_match_all("/[[:upper:]]+/u", $string, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

Output:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(10) "ŽYDRŪNAS"
    [1]=>
    string(10) "PAVARDENIS"
  }
}
```

[<kbd>**Demo**</kbd>](http://3v4l.org/GDWIa)

Comment: @Rizier123 Good edit! I was also searching for the link to the documentation of the `u` option. You was faster! Also interesting to see that it works only for PHP >= 5.3. I would have expected the feature being available in earlier PHP versions too.

Comment: There wasn't much to edit, the answer was already very good :)